# initctl not finding an upstart service

Tags: centos, upstart

I have the following upstart config (see below), on Centos 6.5

the file is in /etc/init/prerender-io.conf,

the service does not appear with the

```
"sudo initctl list" command
```

also,

```
sudo initctl start prerender-io"
```

gives :

```
initctl: Unknown job: prerender-io
```

I've also tried init-checkconf and it said "syntax ok"

```
description "prerender-io"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on shutdown

setuid vagrant
setgid vagrant

respawn

script
    exec node /usr/lib/node_modules/prerender/server.js 2>&1 >> /var/log/prerender.log
end script
```

=====================================================

### update :

the setuid is the problem,

/etc/log/message was having "unknown stanza"

when I did "sudo initctl reload-configuration" ..

removing the setuid and setgid lines solves the problem, but how can I set the user and group ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the setuid and setgid is 
only available since upstart version 1.4

which is why

```
initctl reload-configuration
```

logs "unknowk stanza"